# How can I keep previous datas when the page is refreshed?

Tags: javascript, html, web, model-view-controller

The page refreshes when I use the image upload function in the project. And I'm losing my old data in TextBoxes. How can I keep the previous datas in TexBoxes when the page is refreshed?
The technologies I use:
MVC, C# and web languages

Comment: Your image upload function is called by an AJAX call?

Comment: Yes............

Answer (score 2):

This would be a prime candidate for LocalStorage you can save key-value pairs to be persisted in the browser.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

If you want to store data to persist on browser refresh

```
window.localStorage.setItem('key', data)
```

and when retrieving

```
window.localStorage.getItem('key');
```

Answer (score 0):

use Window.localStorage

like:

```
// Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
    // Retrieve
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}
```

see [More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)